# Suppose that $f \in k[X_1, \dots X_n]$. Show that there exists infinitely many points $(x_1, \dots x_n) \in k^n$ such that $f(x_1, \dots x_n)=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Suppose that $n \ge 2$ and that $f \in k[X_1, \dots X_n]$. Show that there exists infinitely many points $(x_1, \dots x_n) \in k^n$ such that $f(x_1, \dots x_n)=0$. (Hint: form polynomials of one variable by substituting $X_1=x_1, \dots X_{n-1}=x_{n-1})$.

As $k$ is algebraically closed it implies that any $g \in k[X]$ has at least on root i.e $\exists x' \in k$ such that $g(x')=0$.

I'm not getting what they mean by the substitution $X_1=x_1$ etc. The capital $X$'s are supposed to denote the variables of which I'm considering the polynomial ring $k[X_1, \dots X_n]$ so how are they related to the coordinates of a point in $k^n$?

Is the idea here to use the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed to get the result that for $f \in k[X_1, \dots X_n]$ I have a root $x_i$ in the single variable case $k[X_i]$ and then generalize that?

Comment: If you fix $x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}$ in $k$ you get a single-variable polynomial which has at least one root if its degree is $\geq 1$. Since the number of possible choices for $x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}$ is infinite, you get an infinity of roots.

Comment: So $f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, X_n) \in k[X_n]$ and the closedness gives me a root for this polynomial?

Comment: @Jaipur You have to make sure $x_n$ actually appears in $f$, or otherwise choose a different variable to focus on. And you need one variable you can vary as a parameter. So $f$ needs to actually use at least two of the variables in your polynomial ring.